# Multi-Frame Ajax Pagination on a Single Page

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, pagination

I'm working on a WordPress site that utilizes tabbed category/archive pages. Basically, each post type is displayed within a dedicated tab.

On each category page, I have three loops, and each loop is paginated separately. This is working exactly as intended with custom query vars. Each loop is paginated independently, so the site is able to track the current position in each loop on every page load.

Ultimately, I would like to use Ajax pagination. When users click 'next page' on **Tab A**, I don't want to re-load **Tab B** and **Tab C** with the same content, I just want to replace the contents of **Tab A**.

I actually came pretty close to getting this working. I could paginate through each loop via links on the page, but the browser's forward/back buttons no longer worked.

## Here is what I have so far:

```
function doPager() {
    $('.pagination a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadContent($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('tabName'));
        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
        historyedited = true;

        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });
}
```

This function adds the click handler to each pagination link. When I build the pagination links (in php), I set the custom attribute 'tabName' to the base name of the tab I want to load.

My element IDs are named **[base]Tab** and **[base]TabContent**, so by passing this attribute, I can guarantee that I'm loading content from the appropriate tab.

```
function loadContent(url, tabName) {
    destinationTab = '#' + tabName + 'Tab';
    $(destinationTab).fadeTo(250,0).load(url + ' '+ destinationTab + 'Content', function() {
        $(destinationTab).fadeTo(250,1);
        doPager();
        $('.jsDisabled').addClass('hidden');
    });
}
```

This function loads/replaces content.

The above functions are working properly. Where I run into trouble is in the browser history support:

```
if (window.history && history.pushState) {
    historyedited = false;
    $(window).bind('popstate', function(e) {
        if (historyedited) {
            loadContent(location.pathname + location.search);
            // ^ This is the problem.
        }
    });
    doPager();
}
```

As noted in the comment, my issue is with this particular call to `loadContent()`. There is no tabName argument, so as far is the function is concerned, there is no content to load.

Ultimately, I need a way to identify the appropriate tab name and then pass is into this particular call, but that is where I am stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've continued digging and testing different options, and I came to a solution, so I thought I'd share what I found.

To recap, I started with the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    if (window.history && history.pushState) {
        historyedited = false;
        $(window).bind('popstate', function(e) {
            if (historyedited) {
                loadContent(location.pathname + location.search);
                // ^ This is the problem.
            }
        });
        doPager();
    }
}

function doPager() {
    $('.pagination a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadContent($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('tabName'));
        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
        historyedited = true;

        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });
}


function loadContent(url, tabName) {
    destinationTab = '#' + tabName + 'Tab';
    $(destinationTab).fadeTo(250,0).load(url + ' '+ destinationTab + 'Content', function() {
        $(destinationTab).fadeTo(250,1);
        doPager();
        $('.jsDisabled').addClass('hidden');
    });
}
```

The functions are abstracted in a way that I can determine which content frame to load by adding a custom `tabName` attribute to the pagination links. However, my `loadContent()` function received an undefined `tabName` argument when hitting the forward/back buttons.

To solve this problem, I needed to make a few minor changes to my existing script.

---

### Step One: Link Classes

The first thing to do is to assign classes to each pagination link representing the content I want to load:

- `<a class='blogLink'>`
- `<a class='videoLink'>`
- `<a class='reviewLink'>`

### Step Two: Multiple Click Handlers

The next thing I need to do is change my `doPager()` function. Initially, this function applied a single click handler universally to every link within a `.pagination` element. What I really want is a function that looks more like this:

```
function doPager() {
    $('a.blogLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadBlogContent($(this).attr('href'));
        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
        historyedited = true;

        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });

    $('a.videoLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadVideoContent($(this).attr('href'));
        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
        historyedited = true;

        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });

    $('a.reviewLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadReviewContent($(this).attr('href'));
        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
        historyedited = true;

        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });
}
```

With this change, I've registered a unique handler for each link type, and each handler calls a specific content loader.

### Step Three: Multiple Content Loaders

In addition to adding multiple click handlers, I added multiple content loaders.

```
function loadBlogContent(url) {
    loadContent(url, 'blog');
}

function loadVideoContent(url) {
    loadContent(url, 'video');
}

function loadReviewContent(url) {
    loadContent(url, 'review');
}
```

This eliminates the need to copy/paste the original `loadContent()`.

### Step Four: popstate Changes

This is where the original problem actually occured:

```
if (window.history && history.pushState) {
    historyedited = false;
    $(window).bind('popstate', function(e) {
        if (historyedited) {
            loadContent(location.pathname + location.search);
            // ^ This is the problem.
        }
    });
    doPager();
}
```

During the popstate event, `loadContent()` received no `tabName` parameter. To fix this, I replaced the single `loadContent()` call with the the type-specific content loaders I added in step 3:

```
if (window.history && history.pushState) {
    historyedited = false;
    $(window).bind('popstate', function(e) {
        if (historyedited) {
            loadBlogContent(location.pathname + location.search);
            loadVideoContent(location.pathname + location.search);
            loadReviewContent(location.pathname + location.search);
        }
    });
    doPager();
}
```

---

### Edit:

There is a bit of a nasty error in my original answer. Due to how the `doPager()` function is called, I created a scenario where paging through a 'videos' tab would register a duplicate click handler for all other tabs on callback. To resolve that issue, I replaced the single `doPager()` function with frame specific pager registration functions:

```
function registerBlogPager() {
    $('a.blogLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadBlogContent($(this).attr('href'));
        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
        historyedited = true;

        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });
}

function registerVideoPager() {
    $('a.videoLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadVideoContent($(this).attr('href'));
        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
        historyedited = true;

        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });
}

function registerReviewPager() {
    $('a.reviewLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadReviewContent($(this).attr('href'));
        history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
        historyedited = true;

        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });
}
```

I also changed the `ready()` function to call each pager registration once on initial pageload:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    if (window.history && history.pushState) {
        historyedited = false;

        registerBlogPager();
        registerVideoPager();
        registerReviewPager();

        $(window).bind('popstate', function(e) {
            if (historyedited) {
                loadBlogContent(location.pathname + location.search);
                loadVideoContent(location.pathname + location.search);
                loadReviewContent(location.pathname + location.search);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, I made changes to my generic `loadContent()` function. Previously, this function would have registered every click handler, but using the `frameName` parameter passed into this function, I now control which pager registration gets called:

```
function loadContent(url, tabName) {
    destinationTab = '#' + tabName + 'Tab';
    $(destinationTab).fadeTo(250,0).load(url + ' '+ destinationTab + 'Content', function() {
        $(destinationTab).fadeTo(250,1);
        doPager();
        $('.jsDisabled').addClass('hidden');
    });

    if (frameName == "blog") {
        registerBlogPagers();
    }

    if (frameName == "video") {
        registerVideoPagers();
    }

    if (frameName == "review") {
        registerReviewPagers();
    }
}
```